# Import freetrack into steamVR

Tags: kinect, steam, virtual-reality, oculus

I've got an oculus dk1, leap motion for hand tracking and a kinect v1 for positional tracking. With opentrack & opentrackkinect I get as Output freetrack. Is there a method to import that into SteamVR and be so Positional Tracked. I really don't need answers like buy you a vive or something like that. My Vive will came 10 July but I want to test something with the Oculus.

Answer (score 0):

try VRIDGE / RIFTCAT. it should work with opentrack and freetrack data, and translates that to STEAMVR.